Interpolating points and orthogonal polynomials on varying intervals
In general, a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, $\int (\cdot) \, d \alpha(x)$, that defines an inner product on the space of polynomials establishes a notion of orthogonality.
Suppose we have a sequence of orthogonal polynomials of some weight $w$ defined on some interval $[a,b]$, e.g. Chebyshev polynomials. One may ask a legitimate question of whether or not the roots of the given orthogonal polynomials are "good" interpolating points for some class of functions. Similarly, the converse should be interesting, I think. Two questions here

Suppose one knows of some nodal sets that are "good" for approximation, how likely is it for these nodes to be roots of some sequence of orthogonal polynomials and how possible is it to find the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral defining orthogonality?
I'm interested in the question in two scenarios: first, the case where the interval is fixed and hence increasing the size of the nodal set means "taking" more points inside the fixed interval; second, the case where "taking" more nodes means the interval where the approximation is happening is getting bigger.

